# How to specify path to a report from another report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have SSRS on SQL Server 2012 and using report builder to build a drillthrough report. I have a table 6 rows and multiple columns. Each text box has some number in it and I should be able to click on these numbers and go to a different report. Both these reports would be under same folder on report server.

**Problem:**

I am able to do it until this point by following instructions at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-drillthrough-action-on-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs) page.
My problem is I can't use a static link as each text box should direct to it's own unique report. And when I "Specify a report:" using "Browse" button there or by providing static link, same link will be used for all the text boxes in the same column. What I need is to be able to specify path to the report which is of format `/Folder_Name/<valueOfColumn1><valueOfColumn2><nameOfColumn3>;`

**What I tried:**

So I tried to use "Expression" by clicking on "fx" button and provided link as `=Globals!ReportFolderFields!column1.ValueFields!column2.ValueFields!column3.Name`

**Outcome:**

When I try using above methods by using expression it doesn't throw any error but the text box is not clickable (doesn't turn pointer into an index finger). When I used static link by using "Browse" button, the same text box was clickable and was taking me to another report.

What am I missing here? Any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: Somehow this didn't show up correct in the question. </br>What I need is to be able to specify path to the report which is of format "/Folder_Name/valueOfColumn1valueOfColumn2nameOfColumn3"

Comment: Something to keep in mind with report links is they always need to start relative to the home folder, or else be a relative path from the current report's location, is that the case when your expression is evaluated?  -- also, there are some handy tips here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/specifying-paths-to-external-items-report-builder-and-ssrs

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes when I was trying all the combinations in "Expression" by clicking on "fx" button, when I try just =Fields!column1.ValueFields!column2.ValueFields!column3.Name it throws error when I try to save the report.
Error: The ActionInfo.Action.Drillthrough.ReportName expression for the text box ‘<textBoxName>’ 
contains an error: [BC30456] 'ValueFields' is not a member of 
'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Field'.

Comment: I just realized, looking at your string... What you're really trying to do is concatenate several fields together, correct?  Something like Fields!column1.Value & "/" & Fields!column2.Value & "/" & Fields!column3.Name  ...  the current way you have it put together, SSRS is thinking it's one long field name, and that's why you get the error.  I'll post an answer to this effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the field list in your formula needs a few changes.  It looks like what you're really trying to do is concatenate several fields together, with a slash at several spots, in order to get the proper URL format.

Let's assume that the following elements resolve to the strings you need.  (It can sometimes be helpful to verify these resolve to what you're expecting by inserting textboxes for each, individually, in a section of the report for troubleshooting; you can always remove them later.)

```
Globals!ReportFolder
Fields!column1.Value
Fields!column2.Value
Fields!column3.Name
```

If you would like to concatenate these together to use as a URL, together with a few slashes added in the correct places, you'll need to follow the [SSRS conventions on operators in expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/operators-in-expressions-report-builder-and-ssrs), which results in something like this:

```
"/" & Globals!ReportFolder & "/" & Fields!column1.Value & Fields!column2.Value & Fields!column3.Name
```

as always, since this is an expression, it will need to start with an equals sign.

The expression builder doesn't insert operators for you between fields - it's not that smart...

Comment: Thank you for suggesting me the correct way to formatting the expression. That is exactly what I needed.